# Trying to get property 'id' of non-object Laravel error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am working on someone else code in a Project and when I try to run the `php artisan migrate` I am encountering an error!

```
class SeedAdminUser extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        // seed admin user
        $admin = User::create([
            'name' => 'Admin',
            'email' => 'admin@admin.se',
            'password' => Hash::make('password'),
            'plan_id' => null,
        ]);

        $admin->assignRole(['administrator', 'company']);

        $plan = Plan::find(1);
        Subscription::create([
            'user_id' => 1,
            'plan_id' => $plan->id,
            'starts_at' => Carbon::now(),
            'ends_at' => $plan->interval == 'monthly' ? Carbon::now()->addMonth() : Carbon::now()->addMonths(12),
        ]);
    }
```

I am getting an error because of this line `'plan_id' => $plan->id,`

Here is the Error message -

```
   ErrorException 

  Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

  at database/migrations/2021_06_04_055759_seed_admin_user.php:34
    30| 
    31|         $plan = Plan::find(1);
    32|         Subscription::create([
    33|             'user_id' => 1,
  > 34|             'plan_id' => $plan->id,
    35|             'starts_at' => Carbon::now(),
    36|             'ends_at' => $plan->interval == 'monthly' ? Carbon::now()->addMonth() : Carbon::now()->addMonths(12),
    37|         ]);
    38|     }

  1   database/migrations/2021_06_04_055759_seed_admin_user.php:34
      Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError("Trying to get property 'id' of non-object", "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/iSurvey/database/migrations/2021_06_04_055759_seed_admin_user.php", [Object(App\User)])

      +21 vendor frames 
  23  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

Any Idea what is wrong with that line `'plan_id' => $plan->id,` and how to fix it

Comment: if use php 8 can write like this 
$plan?->id
https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nullsafe_operator
else you must check with isset

Comment: are you also seeding a Plan:: model before this seed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because there is no records in plan model,
First check if records exists in plan model

```
dd($plan);
```

or

```
$plan = $plan ? $plan->id : '';
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is exactly what the error says. $plan is not an object, so trying to access a propriety on it result in an error.

Why is $plan not an object? Because `Plan::find(1);` cannot find a plan with an id of 1. $plan is probably `null` so you're effectively running `null->id`.

Since you're running migrations, you might want to make sure this code runs after your plans table is populated. I would give it a shot with `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` (warning: this will empty your db tables and then repopulate them with migrations/seeders) or seeding in general.

Consider also using `findOrFail` instead of `find` to throw an exeception if the model is not found, since your subsequent code in this example depends on the model being found.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your plans are seeded before this migration runs. It's safer to use `findOrFail` instead. This way, you'll know the instant a plan isn't found.